# ObjectName can't find in jetty web project

Tags: java, jetty

I a web project :project compile is ok ,
but when i run jetty ,the console display below error:

```
 Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 Could not initialize class javax.management.ObjectName
```

I can find ObjectName 
[image]

**I use tomcat startup deploy the web project  ,it is ok !**

> Specs:
>
> Mac os x 
>       jdk6      
>       Intelij Idea 
>       jetty

Comment: Put the relevant jars in the classpath !

Comment: would more detail.I can find ObjectName class

Comment: More detail from the stacktrace might help.  It mentioned Nested exception, but you failed to include the entire stacktrace with nested causes.